# Unable to read map property of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fix this but couldn't get it fixed. I have tried many solutions but cannot fix this issue.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Transaction } from './Transaction';

import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState';

export const TransactionList = () => {
  const { transactions } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>History</h3>
      <ul className="list">
        {transactions.map(transaction => (<Transaction key={transaction.id} transaction={transaction} />))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

and the GobalState.js file in context folder is:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'
const initialState = {
    transactions: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Flower', amount: -20 },
        { id: 2, text: 'Salary', amount: 300 },
        { id: 3, text: 'Book', amount: -10 },
        { id: 4, text: 'Camera', amount: 150 }
    ]
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    return (<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
        transaction: state.transactions
    }}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>)
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?  Or is it just blank output?

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Then transactions is probably undefined from your GlobalContext/GlobalState?  What's the code in there?

Comment: Please put your code in the question, not a comment. Also, please include your reducer code too.

Comment: I have attached in the question please check

Comment: You have a typo, you are setting the provider value as an object with property `transaction` not `transactions`, which is why it is undefined. You're missing the s character.

Comment: Thanks alot bro it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are destructing `transactions` while you assigning state value from Provider with `transaction`. Change either of these and It will work fine. Hopefully, It will work!

```
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    return (<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
    //here
        transactions: state.transactions
    }}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>)
```